# Error in syntax of fields while exporting data from Botify

Tags: python, python-requests, bots

I am trying to pull website crawl data from Botify by using Python leveraging the Botify Query Language. Now, to retrieve the crawled values from Botify, the following JSON needs to be sent to Botify using Python `requests.PUT()`.

Below is a sample JSON string provided which works fine when sent to Botify. However, whenever I add few other metadata columns to the below JSON in the `query` --> `dimensions` section , a FAILURE message is being sent back to me.

Basically, I am looking for the proper syntax to include these additional columns (mentioned at the end) into the below JSON in the `query` --> `dimension` section:

Input JSON (Fails):-

```
{
  "job_type": "export",
  "payload": {
    "username": "myID",
    "project": "website.com",
    "export_size": 50,
    "formatter": "csv",
    "formatter_config": {
            "delimiter": ",",
            "print_delimiter": "False",
            "print_header": "True",
            "header_format": "verbose"
        },
    "connector": "direct_download",
    "extra_config": {},
    "query": {
      "collections": ["crawl.20230515"],
      "query": {
        "dimensions": ["url",
                       "crawl.20230515.date_crawled",
                       "crawl.20230515.content_type",
                       "crawl.20230515.http_code",
                       "segments.pagetype.value",
                       "compliant.is_compliant",
                       "metadata.robots.noindex",
                       "http_redirect.to.final.path"
                       ],
        "metrics": [],
        "sort": [1]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But fails when I add the following fields to the `dimension`-list in the query above. I can't get the syntax right.

Fields causing issue in JSON query:

```
compliant.is_compliant
metadata.robots.noindex
http_redirect.to.final.path
```

Error message received:-

```
{'job_id': 1831591, 'job_type': 'export', 'job_url': '/v1/jobs/1831591', 'job_status': 'FAILED', 'results': {'nb_lines': None}, 'date_created': '2023-05-27T17:12:54.074062Z', 'payload': {'query': {'query': {'sort': [1], 'metrics': [], 'dimensions': ['url', 'crawl.20230515.date_crawled', 'crawl.20230515.content_type', 'crawl.20230515.http_code', 'segments.pagetype.value', 'segments.country.value', 'crawl.20230515.is_compliant']}, 'collections': ['crawl.20230515']}, 'export_size': 50, 'connector': 'direct_download', 'formatter': 'csv', 'formatter_config': {'delimiter': ',', 'print_header': True, 'header_format': 'verbose', 'print_delimiter': False}, 'extra_config': {}, 'sort_url_id': False, 'export_job_name': None}, 'user': 'XXXXXXXX', 'metadata': None, 'crawl_date': None}
```

I am new to Botify world and I tried searching the net a lot but didn't find the syntax for using these fields in the JSON query segment.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: _But fails when I add the following fields ..._ Show us the exact actual json you are sending.  Otherwise we're just guessing what you really did.

Comment: _a FAILURE message is being sent back to me_ Also, show us this exact message.

Comment: @JohnGordon thank you for your reply. I have updated the question with the Actual failing JSON string and the exact FAILURE message received. There are many fields that I want to add but just added only 3 (mentioned in the question) to save space.. The fields causing the issue are: `compliant.is_compliant`, `metadata.robots.noindex`, `http_redirect.to.final.path`.

Comment: Show us the full code.  Personally I have no idea what "Botify" is.

Comment: Botify is a website that provides customer's website crawl data to the customer. The query mentioned in the JSON is called BQL (or Botify Query Language). The Python code works fine. Its the BQL section in the JSON that is causing the issue. If you want the complete Python code, i'll provide it.

Comment: How did you create this json that you are sending?  Did you make it by following some example?

Comment: I took it from from an existing code. (the original developer is not an employee of the company anymore). Anyway, the existing JSON works fine, but not when i add the last 3 metrices, namely - `compliant.is_compliant`, `metadata.robots.noindex,` and `http_redirect.to.final.path`. I searched for BQL (Botify Query Language) but didn't solve my issue.